# Prevent form submission when validation fails (Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I just discovered Angular and Material design, and I really love all the features that come out of the box. I created a contact form with validation, which gives error messages when a field is required or is put in the incorrect format. The only thing that is missing is that when the user clicks the "submit" button, they can still send the form to the server. So the error messages don't really help.

**HTML**:

```
<md-content layout-padding="">
  <form name="projectForm" action="/" method="post" novalidate>
    <div layout-gt-sm="row">
      <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input required="" type="email" name="emailAddress" ng-model="project.emailAddress" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/">
        <div ng-messages="projectForm.emailAddress.$error" role="alert">
          <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'pattern']">
        Your email must be in correct format and look like an email address.
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea required="" name="content" md-maxlength="50" ng-model="project.content" rows="3" md-select-on-focus=""></textarea>
  <div ng-messages="projectForm.content.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">
      Your must enter a message.
    </div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</md-button>
```

**JS**:

```
angular
  .module('toast', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.project = {
      //scope stuff goes here
    };
  })
```

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cmelone/pen/VayeQx).

Comment: Just disable the submit button when the form is not valid.

Comment: How would I do that? Wouldn't the user still be able to press enter and submit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the submit button when the form is invalid:

```
<md-button type="submit" class="submit" ng-disabled="projectForm.$invalid">Submit</md-button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't prevent the user from submitting via the enter button.

Comment: Forms in Angular don't typically have an action and are usually handled in the controller. If you followed that pattern you could check `$scope.projectForm.$valid` and just return if it's not valid.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: I tried using `ng-submit="projectForm.$valid && submit()"` but it still lets me use the enter button to submit

Comment: `ng-submit` is the method to call in the controller when the submit button is clicked or enter is pressed. So you would use `ng-submit="submit()"` and then in your `$scope.submit` function in the controller check `$scope.projectForm.$valid` before proceeding with whatever code is needed to process the values. If it's not valid just `return;`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I was just struggling with how to get ngmessages to not allow submission if in an error state, but it makes sense you just check it in the controller function.

Answer (score 2):

This you can try

For angular latest you can validate your form in type script using simple below code

Suppose your form looks like this

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

you can validate its state like

```
 if (!this.userForm.valid) {
    return;
  }
```

Comment: if your FormGroup contains Validators, it can be as simple as putting ```[disabled]="this.userForm.invalid"``` on your button in the html-file

Answer (score 0):

you can use also add [disabled]="projectForm.$invalid"
to:
Submit